# Error encoding model [App\Models\RoleHasPermission] with ID [] to JSON: Recursion detected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm getting an error when storing a permission assigned for a role. The error shows on the line $permission->save();
I don't know how to resolve this issue. need some help.
thanks in advance

here's my controller

```
 public function storePermission(Request $request, $id)
{
    $permissions = $request->permissions;
     RoleHasPermission::where('fkrole_id', $id)->delete();
     foreach($permissions as $permission)
     {
        $permission = new RoleHasPermission;
        $permission->fkrole_id = $id;
        $permission->fkpermission_id = $permission;
        $permission->save();
     }
```

here's my model

```
    class RoleHasPermission extends Model
   {
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = "role_has_permissions";
    public $fillable = ['fkrole_id','fkpermission_id'];
    public $timestamps =false;
   }
```

Comment: A traceback would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the `$permission` variable which you are trying to use as as property with the `new RoleHasPermission`

Try using a different names

```php
public function storePermission(Request $request, $id)
{
    $permissions = $request->permissions;
    RoleHasPermission::where('fkrole_id', $id)->delete();
    foreach($permissions as $permission)
    {
        $roleHasPermission = new RoleHasPermission;
        $roleHasPermission->fkrole_id = $id;
        $roleHasPermission->fkpermission_id = $permission;
        $roleHasPermission->save();
    }
}
```